# Get string between first and last spacial character

Tags: php, regex

I want to find string between first and last **underscore (`_`)** from the below string

I have tried this:

```
$s = '23_The_Sample_Book_145236985.pdf';
$matches = [];
$t = preg_match('/\_(.*?)\_/', $s, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

I want to get output like ...

**`The_Sample_Book`**

But i get like...

**`The`**

Comment: Is `$s` supposed to be a string?

Comment: Just make it greedy: `(.*?)` -> `(.*)` [Explained simple: `(.*?)` -> Take the minimum to make a match; `(.*)` -> Take as much as possible to make a match]

Comment: yes $s is string show my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123 ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope this helps

```
    $s = '23_The_Sample_Book_145236985.pdf';
    $matches = [];
    $t = preg_match('/\_(.*)\_/', $s, $matches);
    print_r($matches[1]);
```

check screenshot
[image]

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @vishu : check your desired ouptput

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
<?php
$s = '23_The_Sample_Book_145236985.pdf';

// Separate the string based on underscore and create an array
$arr = explode('_', $s);

// Remove the first and last array elements
// 23 and 145236985.pdf in the case of this string
$arr = array_slice($arr, 1, (count($arr)-2));

// Rejoin with an underscore
echo implode('_', $arr);
```

Comment: For the truly impatient, please feel free to run this code at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: To be fair - there's a difference between impatience when I know you're adding details to your post, and simply reading an *answer-only* post. I only saw the post and saw no indication you where adding further clarity and usefulness to it. I'm not inpatient in general :-)

Comment: @Martin That's the flow of SO; "in b4 first post". There is plenty of Meta discussion on this. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9758/235923

Comment: @Martin Also, ["I'm not inpatient in general"; You definitely fooled me :)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FaeIr.png)

Comment: hahaha that was crafty timing there! As I said, I had no indicator you where adding more to the answer, I hadn't noticed the fresh timing of your post... ! Perhaps SO can show when an answer is **being** edited? I'll read the meta, cheers

Comment: @Martin Glad I could brighten your day :) definitely check out the meta and see if anyone else has brought up your idea about knowing when a question is **being** edited; honestly that idea never occurred to me and it would be interesting to know what the SO gurus think. Maybe even ask a Meta question requesting such a feature but just be warned that the SO gurus do not care about feelings; it will be strictly about the merit of your question. I've been downvoted to oblivion on Meta plenty of times. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah from my experience meta is quite, er, *elite* but I posted http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276299/show-when-a-post-is-in-the-process-of-being-edited

Answer (score 2):

This should do it, though it does not use regex:

```
$s = '23_The_Sample_Book_145236985.pdf';
//get the position of the FIRST ocurrence of  '_'
$begin = strpos($s, '_') + 1;
//get the position of the LAST ocurrence of  '_'
$end = strrpos($s, '_');
//prints what's in between
echo substr($s, $begin, $end - $begin);
```

Comment: Interesting approach.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.